# How to get the Address of the function call dynamically from the process

Tags: android, security

I am looking for a way to get the address of the function call programatically:
public abstract void onKey (int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) 
from KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener interface.

Are the address of these functions static? i.e is it loaded always in the same memory.

I'm trying to achieve tamper protection from key loggers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question fundamentally doesn't make sense, because you are asking how to take a *function pointer* when, in fact, Java does not have the equivalent of function pointers (you only see references to functions in dynamic dispatch through an object).

Addresses of functions *may* be static or may not exist at all, but this is all transparent to you, as the code is run in the virtual machine.  If you are instead asking at the NDK level, you can surely take the address of the function using a simple `&` in C.  However, at the Java level this is not possible.

You do not clarify, however, why this would help you prevent keyloggers.

Comment: By getting the address of the function in run-time and assuming it is always static, if the address returns a value less-than the supposed address, then there is a high likely possibility that the function call is compromised.

Comment: However, if my logic is incorrect, Is there any other way to programatically detect if the current process is being keylogged? It would be great to know.

Comment: Since the code is running in the VM, and may be interpreted, the function may very well not even _exist_ in memory!  And if you could tell if you were being keylogged, that wouldn't be a very good keylogger :-).  You seem to be conflating the C and VM level, all android programs are written in Java, at which point you are not able to investigate these issues.  However, in general, detecting keyloggers will not be possible (and also, in general, are not too prevalent..)